# I can't install packages cypai2

Tags: python

```
root@6b885b833233:~/factoring/python# pip install cypari2
Collecting cypari2
  Using cached cypari2-2.1.4.tar.gz (127 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing cypari2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to cypari2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to cypari2.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to cypari2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/pari/pari.desc'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

....

```
pip install cypari2
pip install Cython
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: https://discuss.python.org/t/getting-requirements-to-build-wheel-did-not-run-successfully-exit-code-1/30365/2